# Is it possible to set the install mode in Inno Setup (32 or 64 bit)?

Tags: 32bit-64bit, inno-setup

I know that the directive `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64 ia64` can be set, so that Inno Setup will decide on the processor type and install in 64 bit if its possible.

But I need some `[Code]` section function to set the install mode (32 or 64).

Is it even possible?

Example:

This function will return the Java installation architecture (32 or 64):

```pascal
function CheckJavaInstallation()
```

According to the result I want to set Inno Setup to the correct install mode -> Selection of the correct `Program Files` or `Program files (x86)` and in the correct registry (normal or `WOW6432Node`).

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are trying to accomplish?  I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do and what your goal is.

Comment: I elaborated the question a little bit.

Comment: This is a question that should be directed towards the developers of Inno Setup.  What you are asking is if its possible to create a single setup file that supports both platforms.  Honestly I only know of one setup solution program that supports doing that and its not Inno Setup.

Comment: Actually its possible to support more than one platform with a single setup file in inno setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833831/inno-setup-32bit-and-64bit-in-one/4837304#4837304

But I need to determine the install mode by myself, not by inno setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you to create two checker functions: `IsJava32` and `IsJava64`. Then for every file, registry entry, etc you add the two versions with one of the checkers, example:

```
[Files]
Source: "SourceSetupDir32\aFile1.dll"; DestDir: "{pf32}\{#MyAppName}\"; Check: IsJava32;
Source: "SourceSetupDir64\aFile1.dll"; DestDir: "{pf64}\{#MyAppName}\"; Check: IsJava64;
;...
Source: "SourceSetupDir32\aFile4.dll"; DestDir: "{pf32}\{#MyAppName}\"; Check: IsJava32;
Source: "SourceSetupDir64\aFile4.dll"; DestDir: "{pf64}\{#MyAppName}\"; Check: IsJava64;

[Registry]
Root: HKCU32; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty; Check: IsJava32;
Root: HKCU64; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty; Check: IsJava64;
```

```pascal
[Code]

Function IsJava32(): Boolean;
Begin
  { ... }
End;

Function IsJava64(): Boolean;
Begin
  Result := Not IsJava32;
End;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution can be find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5721355/632495). For those that are searching for an answer to this question.